# How to insert javascript into mysql database?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm facing this issue when i try to insert an javascript link

```
Database error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near 'text/javascript'   
src='http://www.domain.com/js/embed.js'></script>'' at line 3
```

Besides that javascript link, it accepted the text and youtube embedded code too . How to rectify this issue ?

and here is the table

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `livedata` (
`livedata_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`livedata_cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`code` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`livedata_id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=78 ;
```

my Htm code

```
 <textarea class="text-input textarea" id="textarea" name="code" cols="100" rows="8"></textarea>
```

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Show the code where the error occurs

Comment: not 100% sure why you would want to do this and the safety of it... however wrap the entry in `mysql_escape_string()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not commenting on what you are actually doing, but your problem is in the apostrophes. Do escape them using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) an [base64_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)